# how to pass multiple parameters to the web API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I want to send something like this to API

```
/GetRegionsByParentIdAndRegionType?parentId=63&regionTypeEnum=5
```

This is the method I use

```
  return Service.get("/GetRegionsByParentIdAndRegionType?parentId= & regionTypeEnum=" +params.parentId+  params.regionTypeId,  (status, data) => {
      callback(status, data);
    });
```

I know this is wrong.
What is the right way to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`URL constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) to create an instance of [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) and then append the search parameters using [`URL.searchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams) property.

Following snippet shows a simple example:

```js
const url = new URL('https://example.com');
url.searchParams.append('parentId', 63);
url.searchParams.append('regionTypeEnum', 5);

console.log(url);
```

Alternatively, you could create an instance of [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) and then concatenate that with the URL string.

Following code snippet shows an example:

```js
let str = '/GetRegionsByParentIdAndRegionType?';

const searchParams = new URLSearchParams();
searchParams.append('parentId', 63);
searchParams.append('regionTypeEnum', 5);

str += searchParams;
console.log(str);
```